# Can we say: "Don't trust THE love?"

Tags: word-usage

I am wondering if we can add "the" at love in the sentence: "Don't trust the love?" (in a poetic way, like if we personalise love).

Comment: If we personalise love we would call it Love. _The love_ would refer to a person that someone loves, as in 'the love of his life' (the one person he felt a strong emotional attachment to).

Comment: @KateBunting Did you mean "_personify_ love"? I also wonder what the OP means by "personalize love". As opposed to universal love, [agape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agape), and [the Love of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_of_God)?

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Yes, I mean personify Love (as if Love is a person). (sorry my english is not so good). Is it possible to put a "the", because I have learnt that we never put "the" with words like life/love/hate...

Comment: It's quite rare to use the definite article with an abstract uncountable noun like "love", but it can occur.  For example, "can you feel the love tonight?" specifies whatever amount of love is currently present and accessible.  We also don't typically use the definite article with proper names.  If you want to say something like "don't trust Love, because she is fickle and careless", then you have *two* good reasons to avoid using "the" -- an uncountable abstract used as if it's a proper name.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for this explanation! Now it's all clear! :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Gary Botnovcan](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/12283/gary-botnovcan)'s [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252590/can-we-say-dont-trust-the-love#comment474853_252590):

---

It's quite rare to use the definite article with an abstract uncountable noun like "love", but it can occur. For example, "can you feel the love tonight?" specifies whatever amount of love is currently present and accessible. We also don't typically use the definite article with proper names. If you want to say something like "don't trust Love, because she is fickle and careless", then you have two good reasons to avoid using "the" -- an uncountable abstract used as if it's a proper name.